# Which API for App Engine and Datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Java and I want to use Datastore with App Engine. Which API should I use?

There is 
'com.google.cloud.datastore' and there is 'com.google.appengine.api.datastore'

More specifically there is 'com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity' as well as 
'com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity'. How do I decide which one to use?

**Edit:** I'm using Java 8 and App Engine standard. I'm also using Eclipse and Cloud tools. When I add Library using 'Google Cloud Platform Libraries', jars for both are added. See: https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoints you mentioned are for the API and the Client Library:

com.google.appengine.api.datastore -> The [API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/api-overview) is specifically designed to work from Apps deployed on AppEngine.

com.google.cloud.datastore -> The [Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) could be used form any Application.

You can see the main difference of them [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/#connecting_to_datastore_name_short_with_app_engine). Nonetheless,the way of calling DataStore would be mostly based on your environment (i.e Java8, Java7, AppEngine Standards/Flex, external applications).

Same applies for the Entities. One is for creating Entities with the [API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/creating-entities), the other one with the methods from the [Client library](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-java).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Please see my edit.   Since I am using app engine, there doesn't seem like there is much difference between the two API. There are some methods in one that are not in the other, but none that draw me to one over the other.